# When I install third party library in react native project it throw me "Module does not exist in package.json"?

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-install, npm-package, package-lock.json

When I install third party library in react native project it throw me "Module does not exist in package.json" then

1. I have to delete Node modules
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. NPM install

then library start working
why is that?

I try above solution and it works but it is really tiring to me.